# Оправка письма по нажатию

Tags: php

Итак друзья, делаю оповещалку на сайт. Суть такая: по нажатию на кнопку(картинку) должно отправляться письмо на почту. На форме есть поле text - это текст письма. Остальные реквизиты известны. Нашёл в качестве примера вот такой код:

```
<? 
mail("joecool@example.com", "My Subject", "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3"); 
?>
```

опробовал, всё работает, но не знаю как прикрутить нажатие кнопки. Предполагаю через пост запрос это сделать. Но в php не очень силён. Помогите

Comment: Нет. Я конечно все понимаю. Но если Вы не представляете, как сделать такую простую вещь, то кто Вам доверил делать "оповещалку" на сайт. Доверьте это дело профессионалам.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас форма, например, <form method="post" action="mailer.php"> создаем файл mailer.php (или ваше значение атрибута action) и пишем в него, что-то типа:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['author']) && isset($_REQUEST['mailtext']))
{
    mail("joecool@example.com", $_REQUEST['author'], $_REQUEST['mailtext']);
    header('Location: '.$_REQUEST['URI']); // Возвращаемся назад на сайт
    exit;
}
else
{
    // Возвращаемся назад на сайт
    header('Location: '.$_REQUEST['URI']);
    exit;   
}
?>
```

Правда, как писал [@Lucky](/users/2804/lucky), если вы не понимаете элементарных приемов написания ПХП кода, то этот пример вы врядли сможете интегрировать в свой сайт